# Is it ok to have a class inside a struct?

Tags: c#, class, struct

In C# a struct is stored on the stack and a class is stored on the heap. Imagine if I have a struct that has a huge class in it. How will this work? Does the struct only contain a pointer to the class, no matter the size of the class? Or will the size of the class also affect the size of the struct?

If the former is true, then I guess it would be ok to have a class inside a struct. If the latter is true, then I think I should avoid do it.

Comment: "In C# a struct is stored on the stack and a class is stored on the heap." That's not true at all, and the rest of the question is reasoning from that false premise. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "has a huge class in it" you mean

```
class HugeClass { ... }

struct MyStruct {

    public HugeClass hugeClass;

}
```

then naturally the field `hugeClass` contains a reference to an object of type `HugeClass`, since classes are reference-types. No matter how huge the actual object is, a reference is always just a reference, so the size allocated by the referenced object does not matter.

Comment: Hmm ok. I just tried doing this to see the size of 'MyStruct'. I used the method: System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)). When HugeClass has 1 int in it, the answer from the given method differs from when HugeClass has 2 ints in it. What's the explanation to this?

Comment: Cannot replicate this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ACJvNi.

As a side note, SizeOf(Type) is obsolete in 4.5.1.

Comment: I see, yes. I used this online compiler: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php, which is the reason I was wondering about the question

Comment: I just tried this in Visual Studio. It seems you are right, the compiler I used was flawed perhaps.

Comment: That one is a Mono compiler, so the difference is probably caused by that. I have no knowledge on Mono, however, so I don't know what's happening exactly.